# how to get a Map<String, String> parameter using soap?

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am trying to do a simple thing but results being really difficult, is it me or im doing something wrong?

I basically want to recieve a `Map<String,String>` as parameter in my soap service. How can I do this? I was reading that non traditional formats require special stuff, any idea?

Thanks

---- My code ---

```
  public String createRequest(@WebParam(name = "name", partName = "name") String name) {
        return "Hello ";
    }
```

When I try to do add `Map<String, String>` I get

```
java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.Map
```

So, I created this model

```
@XmlRootElement
public class optionMap {

    private Map<String, String> optionsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getOptionsMap() {
        return optionsMap;
    }

    public void setOptionsMap(Map<String, String> optionsMap) {
        this.optionsMap = optionsMap;
    }
}
```

And now it runs but I am not sure if this is correct,

```
<message name="createRequest">
...
<part name="optionMap" type="tns:optionMap"/>
</message>
```

Comment: *im doing something wrong?* How can we know without any code?

Comment: Sorry, Ive updated it, didnt do it before since the code is extremely basic and I dont really understand the way of do it, so many tutorials but is very difficult for me to understand them.